# Use Entity framework code first with nosql database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nosql

Can I use Entity Framework Code First Approach with NoSql Database?
And how NoSql can be advantage over SQL Database for a application with large data.

Comment: I've been reading lately that EF7 will have better support for different data models, such as NoSQL. I think this question deserves another look at by the community.

Answer (score 26):

I have been using BrightstarDb (http://www.brightstardb.com/) for the past few months and it offers code-first model generation based on Entity Framework.

BrightstarDb is a NoSql database that is also an RDF triplestore, so it's allows for more complicated relations between Entities than most traditional NoSql databases.

Comment: I agree, this is the only nosql db i have found that supports EF. Your models become "views" to the data, im quite happy with it so far.

Answer (score 10):

> Can i use Entity Framework Code First Approach with NoSql Database ?

No, you can't.

> and how NoSql can be advantage over SQL Database for a application with large data.

[Quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL):

> NoSQL database systems are often highly optimized for retrieve and
>   append operations and often offer little functionality beyond record
>   storage (e.g. key-value stores). The reduced run time flexibility
>   compared to full SQL systems is compensated by significant gains in
>   scalability and performance for certain data models.
>
> In short, NoSQL
>   database management systems are useful when working with a huge
>   quantity of data and the data's nature does not require a relational
>   model for the data structure. The data could be structured, but it is
>   of minimal importance and what really matters is the ability to store
>   and retrieve great quantities of data, and not the relationships
>   between the elements. For example, to store millions of key-value
>   pairs in one or a few associative arrays or to store millions of data
>   records. This is particularly useful for statistical or real-time
>   analyses for growing list of elements (such as Twitter posts or the
>   Internet server logs from a big group of users).

Comment: @Darin, With EF5 now out, is it possible to create some sort of an interface over a NoSQL source and then use it with EF?

Comment: No, that's not possible. EF is SQL oriented.

Comment: This is incorrect, I have had success using both MongoDB and Hadoop with EF Code first 4.0 and up.

Comment: The fact that EF is SQL-oriented doesn't mean that it couldn't be used for NoSQL databases in theory. Just drop the Linq/EntityQuery part and take advantage of entity definition and CRUD, optimistic concurrency for  entity merges etc. Some key-value storages like Redis even support aggregation queries on rows. It could be usable to have EF adapters for NoSQL.